# plink find string in remote .xml file via .bat

Tags: batch-file, ssh, find, putty, plink

I am experiencing a strange issue with SSH, plink, find command and .bat execution.

I want to check a setup.txt file on all my remote machines via putty/plink for a specific string. (around 50-400 putty SSH sessions, depending on my environment)

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
(...)
SET searchPattern="1234567890"
SET fileToCheck="C:\foo\bar\setup.xml"
(...)
:SEARCH_PATTERN
plink -load !session! -l user -pw password find /c /i %searchPattern% %fileToCheck%>>result.txt
(...)
```

The variable session is being populated beforehand and contains a name of a ssh session from putty. The block :SEARCH_PATTERN is then executed for each session. There's more stuff happening at (...) which works just fine but the execution of the **find** command does NOT WORK.

If i do this manually, open putty, type in find /c /i "1234567890" "C:\foo\bar\setup.xml">>result.txt EVERYTHING works but as soon as i execute same command via plink in a .bat file i am getting FIND: wrong format error. I did a lot of googling and still coud not get it to work and i certainly don't want to execute that cmd for 400 remote machines manually.

Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the wrong `find` is being located and that you need to explicitly specify the executable `c:\windows\system32\find.exe` or `c:\windows\syswow64\find.exe`

Comment: i tried both. syswow64 is not found on the machines but system32 one is found. i am still getting FIND: Parameter format not correct error. executing it manually works but not with a .bat file

Comment: pointing my script to the right find.exe with your help didn't solve my issue. i am still experiencing `FIND: Parameter format not correct` issue. I think it has something to do with the quoting in `find "string" file` command. I tried escaping the quotes with \"...\", with single, double and even triple quotes. Nothing helped me so far.

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes are lost somewhere on the way.

So this gets executed on the server:

```
find /c /i 1234567890 C:\foo\bar\setup.xml
```

`find` requites the double quotes around the pattern.

---

It seems that escaping the double-quotes with a backslash helps.

```
plink -load session -l user -pw password find /c /i \"1234567890\" "C:\foo\bar\setup.xml"
```

Comment: it's still not working. i tried escaping with ""pattern"" and \"pattern\". it seems like something happens once i pass the command directly to plink. executing plink -load session -l user -pw password and after the session is connected pasting in find /c /i "pattern" c:\foo\bar\setup.xml works just fine. does plink do any magic when passing on a command directly?

Comment: I get the same results with Win32-OpenSSH `ssh.exe`. So either it share the same bug/feature with Plink or the problem is actually on server side (I've used Win32-OpenSSH server for the test). + It works for me with the `\"` - Did you do a simple test like in my answer? Are are you testing it with the `SET searchPattern=\"1234567890\"`?

Comment: i just executed `plink -load session -l user -pw pw find /c /i %pattern% %fileToCheck%` with `set pattern=\"1234567890\"` and `set fileToCheck=C:\foo\bar\setup.xml`. I am still experiencing `FIND: Parameter format not correct` problem. i tried it now with \"...\", with single, double and triple quotes. Nothing worked. Pointing to the right find.exe at c:\windows\system32\find.exe did not work either. Running my plink command with -v option gives me some extra info and it says OpenSSH Version on remote Server is 6.6 and something about `We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug`

Comment: Works for me against `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6` ([Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH)) - It's probably more about particular Windows build of OpenSSH, rather than about OpenSSH version itself.

Comment: is it somehow possible to see what exactly is happening? like where along the lines do my quotes get missing or what exactly is communicted with the server etc? maybe then i could track down what's causing the `FIND: Parameter format not correct` error

Comment: Do you have a RDP (or similar) access to the server? If you have, run something that never finishes or takes long to finish with the same arguments and check command-line of the running process.

Comment: You can also run something against standard Linux server with standard OpenSSH build to see if the quotes make it to the server.